# What is my SBI IBAN number?

Tags: india, iban

I have been recently accepted for a scholarship and I need to provide my IBAN/BIC number for some purpose of accommodation. My SBI Branch code is 006342 and I wasn't able to find any swift code based on this branch(from whatever I read so far Swift code is equivalent to BIC). Is there some algorithm to find out this IBAN number in INDIA and particularly for SBI banks? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Where is the organisation asking you for an IBAN located? I know nothing about the Indian banking system but if you are going to a European country, Chirag Jain's answer is likely to be incomplete.

Comment: @Relaxed I am going to France(Charpak). The IBAN/BIC was required for accommodation purposes.

Comment: Then Chirag Jain's answer is wrong, your SBI account number is unlikely to work for that purpose and a number like 1068459 certainly won't be accepted by any French organisation expecting an IBAN or trying to set up an automatic transfer (which is what an organisation providing accomodation would typically do). You might need to open an account in France or elsewhere in Europe for this purpose.

Comment: What on earth does "for accommodation purposes" mean? Are you subletting a room in your house and your lodger needs your account number so they can send you their rent?

Answer (score 3):

**IBAN** (International Banking Account Number) is your **account number** only. But in this case, you need **SBI Branch SWIFT code** (not IFSC code, IFSC code is applicable only in India) for international transaction, like **SBI CUTTACK SWIFT code is `SBININBB768`**. This information is enough for your international transaction. Every bank does not have a SWIFT code. Here is the [list](https://www.sbi.co.in/web/nri/quick-links/swift-codes) of all SBI branch of having SWIFT code.

Some other important links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362
- [SBI International](https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/international/international)
- [SBI International Retail Banking](https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/international/international/retail)
- [SBI SWIFT Channels in India](https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/documents/17157/17176/SBI+SWIFT+Channel+in+India/f15e762d-cdc8-4f8a-a749-8e4ea5e3a96c)
- [SBI NRI Remittance Services](https://retail.onlinesbi.com/nri/remittances/sbinri_rem.html)

---

#### UPDATE after the [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108041/what-is-my-sbi-iban-number/108068?noredirect=1#comment203739_108068):

- **An example of an IBAN number**:

Suppose your SBI Account Number is `1068459` then your **IBAN** will be same i.e **`1068459`**.

- **Why is Swift code required or what happens if the Swift code is not available?**

This question can be a new question on **[SE Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)** for the best answer. In short, the Swift code is required to identify the bank and if it is not available you can use nearby bank's Swift Code.

- **What is the relationship between Swift code and IBAN number?**

Again, This question can be a new question on **[SE Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/)** for the best answer. In short, there's no direct relationship between both.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a IBAN number. And tell me why is Swift code required or what happens if swift code is not available? What is the relationship between swift code and IBAN number.

Comment: Sorry, just one last thing. So if I am asked my IBAN number. I just fill my account number as it is. And for the BIC/Swift code I fill the nearby one right?

Comment: I was confused that whether IBAN can exist without Swift code or not.

Comment: Yes your [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108041/what-is-my-sbi-iban-number/108068?noredirect=1#comment203743_108068) is correct!

Comment: What kind of “IBAN” is that? That's certainly not the [IBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) an organisation based in Europe would be expecting...

Comment: India has not yet adopted IBAN, it's mostly Europe and Australia, NZ, etc

Comment: Australia & NZ have not adopted IBAN either, @Dheer. It's still mostly a European thing, though not just an EU thing. Some Asian and South American countries also use the IBAN.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to provide both Swift code and IBAN (International Banking Number ). Swift code is enough for international deposit. And if you need the IBAN. You should ask with the corresponding foreign bank they will provide you.

Answer (score 1):

When making an electronic payment, you need to identify the destination country, bank, branch, and specific account number. The IBAN is a handy way of putting all that information in one place. The first two letters identify the country, the second two are check digits, and the rest identifies the specific bank, branch, and account number. (Exactly how it does this varies: each country has its own format. Irish IBANs contain the bank's SWIFT/BIC code and sort code, but others do it differently. Sort codes are a feature found only in the British & Irish banking systems, not elsewhere.)

However, not all countries use the IBAN system. The only way to get an IBAN is to have a bank account in a country which uses IBAN. India does not. Therefore, the simple and direct answer to your question is that you don't have an IBAN. If you opened a bank account in France you would have one. (All EU countries use IBAN, as do many others.)

However, banks are used to dealing with non-IBAN countries. If you're filling in an electronic form which asks for an IBAN, it's unlikely to accept any Indian account number, but if you talk to a human in the bank, and bring them your bank details, they can probably sort it out for you.